# Apache Sling - OSGI framework exception when starting in Windows

Tags: aem, sling

I received the following error message when starting Sling on Windows with Java 1.7 (see below). I'm using Sling 6 (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/sling/org.apache.sling.launchpad-6-standalone.jar). Any idea what could be wrong?

Last time I tried using the same Sling version on Mac OSX and it worked perfectly.

```
Failed to Start OSGi framework
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uncaught Instantiation Issue: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
     at 
org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.Sling.<init>(Sling.java:245)
     at 
org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate$1.<init>(MainDelegate.java:159)
     at 
org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate.start(MainDelegate.java:159)
     at org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main.startSling(Main.java:244)
     at org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main.<init>(Main.java:107)
     at org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
     at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
     at 
org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getCurrentModule(BundleImpl.java:1046)
     at 
org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getSymbolicName(BundleImpl.java:863)
     at 
org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.SlingFelix.getSymbolicName(SlingFelix.java:32)
     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.toString(Felix.java:1012)
     at org.apache.felix.framework.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:128)
     at org.apache.felix.framework.Logger._log(Logger.java:181)
     at org.apache.felix.framework.Logger.log(Logger.java:114)
     at 
org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:201)
     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:374)
     at 
org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.SlingFelix.<init>(SlingFelix.java:39)
     at 
org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.impl.Sling.<init>(Sling.java:235)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had exactly the same error when using java 1.7. After switching to 1.6 everything seems to be fine. You check your java version by typing java -version in the terminal.

Comment: @Cornel Creanga This advise don't help me(

Comment: Same problem exists with Java 1.8 (no shock).  Sling is used in Adobe CQ5 and the Adobe Experience Manager, so this problem would impact those users as well.

Comment: @Cornel Creanga I tried with Java 6,7 and 8. It just didn't work.